# notification from app request Facebook not received

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-plugins, facebook-app-requests, fb.ui

Im making an application on Phonegap, and therefore using javascript. I have added the facebook plugin, and everything seems to work fine. The user can log in and make app requests to friends using the FB.ui:

```
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'Try this application, and get ready to Guess This Sound!'
    }, requestCallback);
```

The dialog pop up, and when I send an invitation my requestCallback method return OK

```
function requestCallback(response){
    alert("response " + response);
 }
```

However, my friends do not receive any notification about the request. My application is no longer i sandbox mode, and I can't figure out whats the problem is. Since Im using phonegap, I have added ios and android platform on facebook, and I guess no canvas URL is needed.

**UPDATE**

Some users do now receive the notifications from the application, but not everyone.However, when my friend clicks on the notification he receive this message: "The requested page can not be viewed right now. It could be temporary unavailable." Is it because my application is not available on google play and app store for the moment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102378/facebook-invite-request-error-android have the solution to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to wrong set up in facebook developer API. The error still remains, but is because the app is not released yet. To see the solution to this, see:

[Facebook invite request error android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102378/facebook-invite-request-error-android)

Answer (score 1):

You have to Add app in your developer account

facebook -> Apps -> "You app" -> Setting -> add platform -> App on Facebook -> Add any URl

Now you will get app request notification