# Facebook invite request error android

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, facebook-app-requests

When I invite friends from my application, they got a notification on Facebook saying I invited them to my game. However, when they click on the notification they got a error saying: "The requested page can not be displayed right now...". Could the reason be that the application is not published on google play or app store yet? If not, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem will be in your application registration on Facebook developer site. The `invite` button should show a notification to the user, this notification should be linked with your application `URL` on Google PlayStore. **The problem will be in this part**. Make sure you are typing your app link correctly

Here is a useful [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/android-tutorial/) for Facebook registration `API`

Comment: I read the link you gave me, and it says the user will be directed to google play if they don't have the application. I tried to find the URL to my application on google play, but couldn't find it, could it be because the application is not published? I also didn't find where to put the URL on the Facebook developer site. However, it makes a lot sense that I get that error since the user can't be directed to something that does not currently exist.

Comment: IF your app was already registered on Facebook API, you will find section in `Settings` in `Site URL` to write the application link on google play store. For sure your app should be published (Valid URL) to complete this action

Comment: Don`t forget @user1540593 to press vote up if you find my answer useful or accept it if you got what were looking for :)

Comment: The facebook developer page has a new design, so I couldn't find the site URL. But I believe I found my mistake; I had a apk on google play with a different package name than what I wrote in on Facebook. I still don't get it to work, but I will try again when the app i published. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome, I hope I my info was some how useful.  Thanks for your vote up

Comment: Np, if you have any experience regarding phonegap and the facebook connect plugin, check out my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105873/the-redirect-uir-url-must-be-absolute-phonegap-facebook-connect-plugin

Its regarding the error "the redirect_uri URL must be absolute" when login

Answer (score 0):

In my situation there was problem with facebook app settings.

I had only android application registered on facebook and "Single Sign On" filed was off.
Then I changed it to "Yes" value. Problem solved.

Marked area with red in image shows that field.

It has to be set to "Yes" if you want recieper to open when cliking on requets notifation on android device.

[image]